# Use UISwitch to Hide Button with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, button, switch-statement

I am trying to use a UISwitch to hide and show a UIButton on a separate ViewController. However, I am not exactly sure how to set it up on separate ViewControllers.

I have already tried to use a segue to change the button but it did not work because the segue had to be triggered and I didn't want to have to change pages once the UISwitch was turned on or off.

Currently I have the @IBAction setup for the UISwitch and the UIButton:

```
@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {

}

@IBAction func hideButton(_ sender: UIButton {

}
```

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: I added my current code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a protocol with a delegate to call into a different view controller.

I have a simple example that is similar that uses protocols which you can model.
Instead of two view controllers, it is a UIView with a button and a UIViewController.

https://github.com/chrisga/UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Chris has the right idea. You should not reach into a view controller's view hierarchy and manipulate a view. The delegate design pattern is perfect for this. You'd have the switche's IBAction execute a statement like `delegate.hideButton(boolValue)`. (I'm assuming you can read up on the delegate design pattern and figure out how to define a protocol, set up a delegate, etc.